# jQuery UI not working in WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, wordpress

Simple jQuery UI functions, such as the following:

```
(function($) {
    $('ui').sortable();
})(jQuery);
```

Result in an error which would normally indicate jQuery UI was not present.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'
```

However, Chrome's developer tools confirms that it has been loaded. What's up?

Comment: What do you think of removing UI from the title? So it becomes a perfect target for duplicates. Every single day there's someone posting "my jSomething is not working" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simply to stop using jQuery shorthand. This:

```
(function($) {
    $('ui').sortable();
})(jQuery);
```

becomes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('ui').sortable();
});
```